# Downvoted an answer, then marked it as spam - still lost rep

Tags: discussion, down-votes, spam

I saw an answer that was clearly spam.  I downvoted the answer, then marked it as spam.  Eventually the answer was removed by the mods because it was truly spam.

When I downvoted the answer, I lost a rep point.  Shouldn't I get my rep point back since the answer was removed by the mod for being spam?

Am I not employing the downvote function correctly in this case?

Comment: Did you do a recalc?

Comment: Flagging an answer as spam automatically down-vote it, even if the user who wrote it doesn't lose reputation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once the answer is deleted you will regain the reputation during your next reputation recalc. You can visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and request a recalculation be done immediately if you would like to see the +1 be added now.

Bear in mind that if you have other reputation changes during the recalculation it may not be as simple as an `N+1` change.

Comment: I looked at the reputation page, but didn't see the 'recalc' button at the very bottom.  That took care of the issue.  Thanks for the answer.